# Symfony2 Assetic links to undefined route

Tags: php, symfony, symlink, assetic

I recently started using Symfony and have some problems with my assets. I use Assetic and have my assets in Resources/public and linked in bundles/techdemo.

In my twig template I have this sections:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 'bundles/techdemo/css/*'  filter='cssrewrite'%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts 'bundles/techdemo/js/*' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

To get all my .css and .js files into the HTML-head.

This kinda works.. In my Browser Source I get something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ae8ddf1_part_1_style_8.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ae8ddf1_part_1_tags_9.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ae8ddf1_part_1_typeahead.tagging_10.css" />

<script src="/js/c81691d_part_1_bootstrap.min_1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/c81691d_part_1_initial.min_2.js"></script>
<script src="/js/c81691d_part_1_jquery-price-slider_3.js"></script>
<script src="/js/c81691d_part_1_jquery.barrating.min_4.js"></script>
```

But the paths are wrong. I access the project under `localhost:8000/app_dev.php/` thus the files are linked to e.g `localhost:8000/app_dev.php/js/c81691d_part_1_bootstrap.min_1.js` which throws an expeption for an undefined route.

This is my Assetic config:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ TechDemoBundle]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

I have read through numerous sources but haven't found a solution yet. I'm using  the latest 2.8 release.

Edit:

Using an explicit path for one file works fine:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/techdemo/css/style.css') }}" />
```

The link in the source is this: `localhost:8000/bundles/techdemo/css/style.css`

How can I change the dir for multiple assets?

Answer (score 0):

Try change app/config/config.yml:

```
framework:
    templating:
      engines: ['twig']
      assets_base_urls:
        http: [http://yourhost.com]
```